# Fill hidden HTML form field with submitted date & time for display as HTML text on phpmailer confirmation screen

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, phpmailer

I would like to have the hidden field filled with the date & time onsubmit and that field's POST data echoed on the phpmailer confirmation page so they can print it out as proof of submission (forms must be submitted before a deadline sort of thing).  I tried working the script I found on another post and the form is processed and nothing fails, but the date/time are not showing up....

Script on HTML form page...

```
<head>
<script language='JavaScript'>
function getTime(){
var date = new Date();
var d = date.getUTCDate();
var day = (d < 10) ? '0' + d : d;
var m = date.getUTCMonth() + 1;
var month = (m < 10) ? '0' + m : m;
var year = date.getUTCFullYear();
var h = date.getUTCHours();
var hour = (h < 10) ? '0' + h : h;
var mi = date.getUTCMinutes();
var minute = (mi < 10) ? '0' + mi : mi;
var sc = date.getUTCSeconds();
var second = (sc < 10) ? '0' + sc : sc;
var loctime = month + day + hour + minute + year + "." + second;

document.getElementById('localTime').value = loctime;
}
</script>
```

Form action...

```
<form method="post" action="../cgi-bin/test_dummy.php" name="Work Record" autocomplete="off" onsubmit="getTime()">
```

Input field in form...

```
<input type="hidden" id="localTime" name="localTime" value="">
```

End of phpmailer script where I am trying to get the time/date to show in confirmation message...

```
if(!$mail->Send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

$localTime = $_POST['localTime'];

echo '
    <html><img src="//images/pinktest.png" width="678" height="110">

<h2><b>'.$first_name.' '.$last_name.', '.$license_type.' '.$localTime.'</b></h2>
```

Comment: You really shouldn't use this approach. Main reason - never ask client for anything you can get on server - just use server code to get current time. Otherwise it would be very easy to forget this timestamp for use (e.g. user can send you any timestamp he wants, which means this can't serve as proof)

Comment: I agree with @Dmitry . You can do this check in PHP. Check for the date, and if fails, send back a message.

Comment: you could send a hash / digest of the message back to the person submitting the form ( via email ), record the same hash / digest in the db ( against that form submission / user ) and include the hash in the message sent. If all three match then it must be valid - along the lines of the "commitment scheme"

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the issue was with my actual submit button.  It works just fine now.  I understand the concerns of why I wouldn't want to do this but this is all I am familiar with and if any of our users even had the slightest idea of how to edit code to alter what is being posted i would be absolutely shocked.  thank you for the feedback... you guys are great!